# How Binding internally works? Is IObserver more optimized than traditional INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: .net

I used **INotifyPropertyChanged** for the first time in a simple WPF application. I want to know how exactly Binding internally works. Is it the CLR which checks for any class with **INotifyPropertyChanged** implementation and records the subscribers that need to be informed about the changes?

While I tried this on .NET 3.5, I read about **IObserver** available with .NET 4.0. Is **IObserver** more optimized than the traditional **INotifyPropertyChanged** way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IObservable<T> and INotifyPropertyChanged - is there a connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162796/iobservablet-and-inotifypropertychanged-is-there-a-connection)

Comment: No. I have asked how binding internally works. The former part of my question is about internal working and the latter about performance. I am not asking the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INotifyPropertyChanged is just an interface that a class can implement. It is up to the implementors to determine how to handle the actual changes.

In the case of WPF, when a one way Binding is created, the binding object verifies if the object implements INotifyPropertyChanged. If it does, it attaches an event handler. It might be a weak reference event handler, because of memory leak concerns, but let's skip that detail for now. When the PropertyChanged event is changed, the Binding object verifies that the Path it has is the same as the PropertyName coming from the event. If yes, the binding fetches the value and sends it over to the target over the Dispatcher. The CLR itself doesn't care what the event is; its just a matter of subscribing to the PropertyChanged event via standard .Net events. An important point is that the INotifyPropertyChanged, like the name implies, is specific eventing to indicate that an object's property value has changed.

The IObserver interface is meant for generic notifications. These notifications *can*, I guess, be property notifications but it is meant to be a very generic interface.

As to optimizations, it all depends on the implementation, not the interface itself.

Answer (score 2):

The WPF binding system looks for the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, not the CLR. The WPF binding engine has lots of moving parts, but you can assume that the [BindingExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpression.aspx) is the one that ultimately subscribes to the PropertyChanged event.

The IObserver interface serves a different function than INotifyPropertyChanged. The latter is used to indicate when a property's value has changed (a very specific task), the former is used to define a generic/reusable [observer design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

I don't believe the WPF binding system supports IObserver and I doubt it would anytime soon.