# Why do ViewModels need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged or use Dependency Properties?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, dependency-properties, inotifypropertychanged

I've seen many Tutorials about the MVVM-Patern but I still don't get why I need to get a Dependency-Property or an `INotiyfyPropertyChanged`-Property if I want to send information from the ViewModel back to the View.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependency properties provide built in change notification for when a property changes which means WPF knows when a controls value has changed.

Your ViewModel types do not, by default, provide any mechanism for change notification so if they don't support either of these options how is the view supposed to know when a property in your viewModel has been changed?

You need your viewModel to use either of these options so that the view can be notified when a property value changes.

This means if a property value is changed in code, the user interface is updated and if a property is changed by user input your viewModel (and ultimately your model) is also updated to reflect these changes. (basically both sides of a binding require a way of communicating a property change to each other).

The `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface is the preferred method as it means your viewModels are not specific to WPF and can be used by other user interface technologies. also, dependency properties can only be used in types that derive from `DependencyObject`.

Answer (score 1):

First: You do not need to  use `INotifyPropertyChanged` or `DependencyObject` at all.

But, and this is the central point in using Binding, there is some Pub / Sub Mechanism in
the Binding, which is listening to those `PropertyChanged` events and doing the update
of the view in case a relevant property for Binding has changed.

Here is more information on that:

[SO on how binding works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912778/how-binding-internally-works-is-iobserver-more-optimized-than-traditional-inoti)

[Pub Sub aka Publish Subscribe Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

`INotiyfyPropertyChanged` - This property we used in the viewmodel so that if there happens any changes in the UI this property will reflect those changes.